# Owners returns an empty list

Tags: tapkey

I'm making a request to the tapkey endpoint to get owners associated with a particular acccount, but on checking owners, it's an empty list:

```
const token = await this.getAuthorizationCodeToken()
try {
  const {data: owners} = await axios.get(
    `${this.baseUrl}/owners/`,
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  )
  console.log('owners: ', owners)
  return accountIds
} catch (error) {
 // throw error ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed privately later, incorrect token (with incorrect user) has been used to retrieve Owners.
User in the token had no owner accounts and therefore the list was empty.
As you confirmed later, once you used correct token (over Google ID), everything worked as it should.